# Upgrading Processor - Dell Latitude e5400

Tags: laptop, cpu, motherboard

My laptop is Dell Latitude E5400. Recently, I replaced the old 240gb/5400rpm hard drive with a Kingston 240gb SSD. I also added 2gb/800mhz more RAM and now it has 4gb in total. So, I decided to replace the processor (Intel Core 2 Duo T7250/2mb L2 cache) with a faster one. (These are the numbers on the top of the processor if they help: LF80537, V947A355, SLA49)

This is the list of processors that I am interested in:

1. Intel Core 2 Duo - T9300 - (6M Cache, 2.50 GHz, 800 MHz FSB)
2. Intel Core 2 Duo - T9500 - (6M Cache, 2.60 GHz, 800 MHz FSB)

**My Questions are**:

1. Will it work? I am really confused. Can somebody explain the difference between BGA479, PGA478, PPGA478 sockets? Are these T9300 and T9500 processors compatible with my motherboard socket?
2. Is the BIOS (Version A13) going to recognize the new processor?
3. Do I need to change my 65W power cable with bigger one if the new processor is with the same 35W consumption as the T7250?
4. Is the upgrade worth it? I am using the laptop only for small graphic design works with Corel Draw, Adobe Illustrator and Adobe Photoshop. Is there going to be a significant improvement in the performance?

***Note:** I am not interested in buying new computer.

[image: Picture of the CPU]

Comment: Your CPU isn't user replaceable

Comment: Most laptop CPUs cannot be replaced. If you have one of the rare ones that is replaceable, only the same socked will physically match. Look at the tech specs for your computer (they'll be available on support.dell.com) and learn what socket you have, then see if there are other CPUs that will fit that exact same socket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to look into the specifications of the motherboard of your laptop. If you look at [specs](https://ark.intel.com/products/31728/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-T7250-2M-Cache-2_00-GHz-800-MHz-FSB) of the CPU you currently have, it seems it's available as BGA and PGA.

BGA refers to [Ball Grid Array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_grid_array) and usually means that the CPU is soldered to the board. In that case you would not able to replace the CPU.

You would have to check your manual on whatever CPUs would be supported, assuming you can replace them. By taking a picture you could also let people help identify it, after all you said it's information from the CPU so I guess you opened the laptop. Generally I would expect there to be some kind of screw or similar to loosen the CPU if it was removable. If there is nothing like that in place you probably will not able to replace it.

Lets have a look at the specs of the CPU and what sockets they support:

- [Intel® Core™2 Duo Processor T7250](https://ark.intel.com/products/31728/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-T7250-2M-Cache-2_00-GHz-800-MHz-FSB): PBGA479, PPGA478
- [Intel® Core™2 Duo Processor T9300](https://ark.intel.com/products/33917/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-T9300-6M-Cache-2_50-GHz-800-MHz-FSB): BGA479, PGA478
- [Intel® Core™2 Duo Processor T9500](https://ark.intel.com/products/33918/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-T9500-6M-Cache-2_60-GHz-800-MHz-FSB): BGA479, PGA478, PPGA478

It should be save if you have the same number as it would be the same socket. So at least the T9500 should be a fit - if you get the right version.

As for whenever it's a good upgrade it depends on the kind of work you do. You told us which applications you're using but didn't say aynthing about the actual work. Depending on it a faster GPU would be more of an upgrade (unlikely that's replaceable).

Oh and consider including information from responses you might get on your [CNET post](https://www.cnet.com/forums/discussions/upgrading-processor-dell-latitude-e5400/).

Comment: Seth, thank you for the information! Your answer is very helpful. Actually, I have a picture of the CPU before I changed the thermal paste.[link](http://imgur.com/KexvEi9). I think that this is the screw you are talking about. What is your opinion?

Comment: Yep, from what little experience I got with laptop CPUs I'd assume you can change that model for another one.

Comment: Thank you again for the fast response, Seth ! Really appreciate your help. So, all of the answers until now say that the T7250 in my Dell e5400 can be replaced with faster T8300/T9300/T9500 and there should be no problem at all, as long as the new processor is with the Socket P (PGA478 or PPGA478). On the other hand, the GPU (Intel GMA 4500MHD) can't be replaced. It is soldered to the motherboard.

Comment: Yes, the GPU is most likely soldered and yes, that would be my assumption. Though it could be wrong. So you will have to make that judgment yourself. I haven't replaced a laptop CPU myself, it's all based on the information I found about the CPUs. As there is at least [one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D5WkAyf90qY) video available of someone who claims to change the CPU on your model it seems to be pretty save that you can, at least, exchange the CPU.